# How to make Sprint Boot 2 actuator path based on application properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a microservice application with Spring Boot 2, which used my own library to propagate new endpoint to itself by using actuator functionality - my own actuator implemented an MvcEndpoint interface, and contained 'path' variable which got real API mapping from application.yml of microservice that used this library.

But after I recoded my library to spring boot 2, I have an issue - **id** property on **@Endpoint** annotation contains only constant value (as every annotation properties), and I haven't found way to change API path of my actuator endpoint to something like '**/api/v1/my-service/my-actuator-endpoint**'.

I tried to write this in my application.yml of microservice:

```
endpoints:
  my-actuator-endpoint:
    path: /api/v1/my-service/my-actuator-endpoint
```

But this endpoint still accessible only from /my-actuator-endpoint , which means only by its id.

How can I make this be accessible by custom path like /api/v1/my-service/my-actuator-endpoint, which will be configured in application.yml?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, needed to add this property to application.yml:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      path-mapping:
        my-actuator-endpoint: api/v1/my-service/my-actuator-endpoint
```

Answer (score 0):

you can expose actuator endpoints by setting configuration in property file like this

```
management.context-path=/manage
```